# Silk Test 2009 R2 - Too Many arguments to function Click

Tags: silktest

I have included the file extend/explorer.inc under SILK runtime. When I try to run the test, I am seeing following error

htmlpage.inc(378) - Too Many arguments to function Click
htmlpage.inc(399) - Too Many arguments to function Click
explorer.inc(361) - Too Many arguments to function Click
explorer.inc(371) - Too Many arguments to function Click

how do I resolve this? What is causing this error.

Answer (score 1):

it would help greatly if you could post the code line of your test where this error happens, so we could see with which parameters you are calling the Click method.

Are you by any chance using 4Test's reflection like mechanism (the '@' operator) to call the click function with more than four arguments?